# Expand navigation menu after button click via CSS / HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So imagine that I have narrow navigation menu like this:

Narrow menu:

```
.narrow-menu {
    width: 60px;
    /* Some more conditions */
}

|[X]| <-- after clicking this button menu should expand as below
|   |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
| F |
| G |
```

As you see in sample above there is `[X]` button, after clicking It menu should expand as below:

Full menu:

```
.full-menu {
    width: 300px;
    /* Some more conditions */
}

|Profile Photo [X]| <-- after clicking this button menu should became narrow again
|Some Info        |
|                 |
|  Home           |
|  News           |
|  Contacts       |
|  About Us       |
|                 |
```

As you see in sample above, after clicking `[X]` button again, It should make menu narrow again.

Of course these menus have different *HTML divs*, so maybe to achieve It I don't need to edit CSS at all? Have you ideas how could I achieve It?

You could test It at [**JS fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p3u4tjLy/)

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: could you share relevant HTML and JQ so we can help you better?

Comment: @guradio I don't have ideas how can I achieve It via CSS, that's why I'm asking your help, how could It be done.

Comment: @MihaiT I've created JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p3u4tjLy/

Comment: At Fiddle as you see, both menu now are shown. Should be shown only `Narrow menu`, after clicking `[X]` button It should hide and add content from `Full menu`

Comment: @Infinity posted an answer below ( both jsfiddle and snippet ) + another solution. let me know if it works for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i am sure there is an easier and cleaner way to do this. but this solution works

for this to work. you need the jQuery library

in jsfiddle just click where it says JAVASCRIPT and select Jquery 3.1.0 from frameworks/extenstions

in your project add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your `<head>` section

Changed also a bit the html structure. ( moved the nav titles inside their containers )

see **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3u4tjLy/3/)**

**or** code snippet below :

```js
var narrowbut = $(".leftside-narrow li:first-child a"),
    fullbut = $(".profile-info li:first-child a")
  
$(narrowbut).click(function(){
    $(".leftside-narrow").animate({'left':'-200%'},350);
    $(".leftside").animate({'left':'0%'},350);

});  
$(fullbut).click(function(){
    $(".leftside-narrow").animate({'left':'0%'},350);
    $(".leftside").animate({'left':'-200%'},350);

});
```

```css
.leftside-narrow,.leftside { position:absolute;top:0}
.leftside { left:-200%;}

.leftside-container {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -350px !important;
 padding-bottom: 170px !important;
}
.leftside-narrow {
 width: 100px;
}
.leftside {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #042643;
 height: 100%;
 
}
.leftside a {
 color: #9aa8b3;
}

.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.submenu a {
  background-color: #5d82a0;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #5d82a8;
}
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.leftside ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
  /*  position: fixed;*/
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
 background-color: #042643;
}
.leftside-menu a img {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: solid #284158 1px;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #5d82a0;
    color: white;
 height: 100%;
}
li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftside-container">
  
   <div class="leftside-narrow"> 
     Narrow Menu
   <li><a href="#"> [X] </a></li>  
   <li><a href="#news"><img src="images/news.png"/></a></li>
   <li><a href="#contacts"><img src="images/contacts.png"/></a></li>
  </div>

  <div class="leftside"> 
     Full Menu
   <div class="leftside-menu"> 
    <div class="profile">
     <div class="profile-info">
      <li><a href="#"> [X] </a></li> 
      <span class="profile-span name">John Doe</span><br>
      <span class="profile-span">Designer</span><br>
     </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
     <ul class="mainmenu">     
      <li><a href="#news"><img src="images/news.png"/> News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacts"><img src="images/contacts.png"/>Contacts</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div> <!-- End of leftside-menu -->    
  </div> <!-- End of leftside -->
 </div>
```

or you could use this [Slide Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) to use `slide` instead of `left:-200%`

for eg :

```
$(".leftside-narrow").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
$(".leftside").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

and ofcourse more code for this to work. but this implies uploading the jQueryUI library

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I can't understand why It's not working for me. I've tried locally, after It I have created fiddle as yours, but It still not working, can't understand how did you achieve It working? https://jsfiddle.net/9cak0xm5/1/ Maybe I missing something...

Comment: well you need to add the jQuery library. as you see...in my fiddle and in the code snippet the jQuery is added // also edited my answer to how you should add jQuery

Comment: I've already added jQuery lib in head section, but still not working. This could happen that I'm trying to test this html locally (from c:/index.html)? Maybe jQuery not working in this case?

Comment: dunno about that. as you can see here...it works both in jsfiddle and in code snippet. did you check your console ? any errors ?

Comment: No errors, simple no action after clicking `[X]`. Looks like not working locally, I've pasted my full code to JS Fiddle and It worked. Thank you for your help!